# Swift how to make public variable in NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, variables

This is my class:

```
public class NewsListItem: NSObject {
    var entries: [NewsListEntry]? = []
}
```

I can parse JSON string into this object using EVReflection:

```
let newsListItem = NewsListItem(json: responseObject)
```

But how do i make entries public? I Can't access newsListItem.entries

Comment: Side note, but why is `entries` optional? You've initialized it to an empty array; making it optional allows for it later to be reassigned to `nil`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Without specifying any access controls, variables are `internal` by default, which means that unless you're writing a module, you should be able to access `entries`. If you *are* writing a module, try adding `public` next to the variable declaration, and if that doesn't work, what error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

You can declare and access class variable in a NSObject class like below.

```
public static var entries = ""
```

and can acess from class name

```
print(NewsListItem.entries)
```

Comment: For the purpose of the class (which is assumably parsing JSON objects), you would most like want to stick with just `public var` so you can create instances.